# Print a list of strings in a grid format - Python

Tags: python, list, grid

Although this question is similar to a few others on here, many of the existing answers have been too confusing/difficult for me to understand.

Anyway, I simply would like to know if there is a way to print a list, like this: `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` in a grid format (in the python IDLE),

like this...

```
a b
c d
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Reshaping with `numpy`? Looping over slices? Anything?

Comment: Of course there's a way. What trouble are you having doing it your way?

Comment: @CoryKramer Not tried anything. However, I've read a bit, but I'm not that experienced so I didn't really know where to start.

Comment: @PeterWood I'm not sure what you mean? I don't really have a way of doing it at the moment.

Comment: Start with making it work for an empty list, then a list with one item, it gets interesting with two items, you'll know what you're doing with 3 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres one way to do it:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

def printGrid (numsPerRow, l):
    printStr = ""
    numsInRow = 1
    for i in range(len(l)):

        item = l[i]
        if numsInRow % numsPerRow == 0:
            printStr += "{0}\n".format(item)
            numsInRow = 1
        else:
            printStr += "{0}\t".format(item)
            numsInRow += 1
    return printStr

print printGrid(2, l)
```

Or you can do it with lists instead of string manipulation:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

def printGrid (numsPerRow, l):
    copyL = l[:]
    numsInRow = 1
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if numsInRow % numsPerRow == 0:
            copyL[i] = copyL[i] + "\n"
            numsInRow = 1
        else:
            copyL[i] = copyL[i] + "\t"
            numsInRow += 1
    return copyL

print "".join(printGrid(2, l)) ,
print l
```

Comment: Thanks that first one worked perfectly. But just for future reference, could you explain what the "item" variable is for and also what the "{0}"s are for. Sorry if it seems obvious.

Comment: `item` is just the item from the list we are working with, it could easily be replaced with only using `l[i]` and not using the `item` var, but it was my personal preference to declare that variable. Also the `{0}` is for inserting the item into the string. [You can read this link for more info.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: That's great! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop with `step` equals to your grid width and slice with joining your chars into string with spaces between. In my solution instead of list of chars I apply string. String == list of chars. Don't forget about this.

```
>>> strq
'abcdefghijk'
```

This will be your code:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> for el in range(0,len(strq),n):
...     if el < len(strq)-(n-1):
...         print ' '.join(list(strq[el:el+n]))
...     else:
...         print ' '.join(list(strq[el:]))
... 
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k
>>> n = 4
>>> for el in range(0,len(strq),n):
...     if el < len(strq)-(n-1):
...         print ' '.join(list(strq[el:el+n]))
...     else:
...         print ' '.join(list(strq[el:]))
... 
a b c d
e f g h
i j k
>>>
```